# ¿Cómo coloco una imagen encima de un video?

Tags: html

Necesito poner 3 imágenes encima de un video de fondo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>pieza clima</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
      <source src="./img/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div>      
      <div id="content-text"></div>       
    </div>      
  </body>
</html>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Lo ideal sería que encapsularas el video y las tres imágenes en un `div` y dentro de este agregar el video con las imágenes, ya por `css` posicionas las imágenes encima del video

Comment: Puedes modificar el código de ariba ?

Comment: Hola Lucas y bienvenido, ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Añade algo más de información a  la pregunta: ¿Cómo quieres posicionar las 3 imágenes? ¿quieres que el video se esté reproduciendo en el fondo? ¿O son las imágenes para cubrir el video? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta sería una posible solución a lo que necesitas

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <title>pieza clima</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">

  <style>
    .container-main {
      position: relative
    }
    
    .container-main video {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      min-height: 300px;
    }
    
    .container-main .img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20%;
      max-width: 60px
    }
    
    .img-1 {
      left: 10%;
    }
    
    .img-2 {
      left: 50%;
    }
    
    .img-3 {
      right: 10%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-main">
    <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png" class="img img-1" />
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png" class="img img-2" />
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png" class="img img-3" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Perfecto gracias.